# Magento: rewriting multiple URLs (from) to one target (to) using a regex?

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite some of my URLs using a regex. This is my rewrite stuff in config.xml of my module.

```
<rewrite>
    <My_Module>
        <from><![CDATA[#^/(abc)|(def)/configuration/#]]></from>
        <to>/config/configuration/</to>
        <complete>1</complete>
    </My_Module>
</rewrite>
```

As you see, what I am trying to achive is to rewrite all urls that contain *abc/configuration* or *def/configuration*. This does not work. So how can I add multiple URLs to the same rewrite in Magento? I dont care if its done with a regex or a line for each rewrite in config.xml, so far I did not manage to figure it out either way.

Thanks!

**Addition**: I *solved* this now by using:

```
<from><![CDATA[#^/.+/configuration/#]]></from>
```

This did the trick in my case :) ... I am still interested how to solve it the first way though. If anybody knows, please post anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Select first OR second is written like this /(first|second)/

Code bellow is working in 1.8 magento.

`$2` will be replaced with what ever `(.*)` captures.

```
<config>
    <global>
        <rewrite>
            <My_Module>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/(abc|def)/configuration/(.*)#]]></from>
                <to><![CDATA[/config/configuration/$2]]></to>
                <complete>1</complete>
            </My_Module>
        </rewrite>
    </global>
<config>
```